# Cpu usage in the output of top

Tags: cpu, top

I am looking at the output of top.

> top - 16:11:19 up 31 days,  2:37, 10 users,  load average: 17.01, 16.99, 17.00
>
> Tasks: 470 total,  18 running, 452 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
>
> Cpu(s): 76.5%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 23.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

Several questions about CPU usage:

(1) is "us" part in the third line same as "load average/number of cores" or something I heard people mentioned "CPU utilization"?

(2) for the us part, "man top" says

> us  --  User CPU time
>
> ```
>      The time the CPU has spent running users’ processes that are not niced.
> ```

What are "processes that are not niced"?

(3) some says "CPU utilization" is a better measurement than load average. So how to get "CPU utilization"? If I sum up the %CPU column for all processes, is that "CPU utilization" or something else different than "CPU utilization * number of cores" and load average?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a couple of sources:
* [Top: Linux Command](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm),
* nice article on [top usage patterns](http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/using-top-more-efficiently_89.html).

> (1) is "us" part in the third line
>   same as "load average/number of cores"
>   or something I heard people mentioned
>   "CPU utilization"?

the "us" field shows CPU Time in User Mode. See [CPU Modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes).

> What are "processes that are not
>   niced"?

A process "niceness" is an internal numeric value that essentially defines how nice a process is being to the CPU. A low priority process, that sleeps and takes very few processing power (cycles) when active is a "nice" process.
Niceness can be positive or negative. A negative niceness is a process that is demanding more priority and taking more cycles. Not nice at all. A positive niceness is a process taking few cycles, sleeping most of the time and having low priority. Very nice. See [Nice](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Nice).

So the "us" field shows you how much CPU time the negative niceness (the not nice) user mode processes are taking. To see the "niced" processes look at the **"ni" field**.

> (3) some says "CPU utilization" is a
>   better measurement than load average.
>   So how to get "CPU utilization"? If I
>   sum up the %CPU column for all
>   processes, is that "CPU utilization"
>   or something else different than "CPU
>   utilization * number of cores" and
>   load average?

To see the CPU utilization, look at the **"id" field**. This is the idle time. CPU utilization is thus, 100 - id.

Comment: Note that I purposely avoided the initial question at (3). I respectfully disagree with what you have been hearing. They have different purposes and thus should be used for what they were meant. I couldn't have it said any better than what you will read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29#Load_average_is_not_CPU_utilization